# Console menu with dynamic options

Tags: c#

I have a list of text files that I want to be able to open in a console application.

The output I want is something like:

> 1. List1.txt
> 2. List2.txt
> 3. List3.txt
>
>    etc

Once I get this output I want a way of being able to call one of those files and have it open via `Console.ReadLine();`

What I'm doing at the moment is

```
string[] FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"Itemized\", ".txt");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine,FileNames));
```

This allows me to get as far as getting list that looks like:

> Itemized\List1.txt
>
> Itemized\List2.txt
>
> Itemized\List3.txt

If I know the number of files in the folder I can hard code it but the problem I have is that any number of files could be present.

So what im looking for at the moment is a way to append a scaling numeric value to each file and remove the folder-name from the front of it.

I've tried using a for loop to get it to work but can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something clean and simple:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirFolderPath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Itemized");
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirFolderPath);

        if(!dir.Exists)
        {
            dir.Create();
        }

        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");

        for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            string line = string.Format("\n{0}-{1}", i, files[i].Name);
            Console.WriteLine(line);   
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This looks amazing testing it out

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
var fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"Itemized\", "*.txt").Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, fileNames));
```

Comment: Only works if I remove `"*.txt"` any idea why ?
Everything displays as text documents and when i remove it the list forms without them. Either way you helped me get closer to what i want have an upvote

Comment: @Spooler for me it works fine. The only problem in my example is that you didn't get any line numbers. To reach this your have to output the `fileNames` using an for loop like @Ephraim used it

Comment: Yea that's why he got the accepted answer, ( having shown the for loop to add the value).
Anyways now it's time for me to figure out how to provide user interaction for this menu